Firebase: Bigquery import segments is taking too long
We have been using for the past year firebase segments in order to personalize certain parameter for users in our app. We currently use Big Query  and then firebase's big query integration in order to import these segments (docs:https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/import-segments).
However a few days ago we uploaded new segments and now the integration seems stuck in "Import in progress
Please allow for up to 45 minutes" as shown:

This updates usually takes 3 hours but it's been more than 24 in our case and no signs of progress.
Is there someone that had similar issues we this feature?
Thank you in advance!
We have waited and checked health monitors to see if there was any issue and none whatsoever.

You should reach out to Firebase support to get help on this.  Asking if anyone had the same problem is not really on-topic for Stack Overflow.
